# Azure Web Application Insights "Servers" Data is Empty

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have a MVC 5 web app hosted on Azure using Application Insights.  App Insights was installed via a NugGet package in VS 2015 and the Key is set correctly.  I have included the JS portion in the bottom of my page template.  I am receiving ALL App Insight data EXCEPT the "Servers" section, which displays lower level perfmon data (Process CPU, Avail, Memory, Process IO Rate, etc).

The ApplicationInsights.config file appears to contain the necessary module:

```
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector">
```

Here is a screenshot from the Portal:
[image]

I am running this on the B1 App Service Plan level.  I cannot find any information that could indicate this information is not available at this tier.

Comment: Do you have the [Application Insights Extension](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/new-application-insights-functionality-on-azure-websites-with-the-application-insights-website-extension/) added to your web app?

Comment: Yes, it shows version 1.3.0 of the extension is installed (No Update available -- so I assume this is the latest).  All of the NuGet packages for AI are also installed and up-to-date.

Answer (score 3):

In the [Performance Counters](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-monitor-performance-live-website-now/#performance-counters) section of the "Install Application Insights Status Monitor to monitor website performance" article they sneak in a "Not for Azure web apps" comment.

I believe they are making a distinction between Performance Telemetry, which you can get for web apps, and Server Performance Counters, which you cannot.

Comment: This is what I figured, thanks for confirming. It makes sense that the CPU/Memory is monitored/aggregated at the App Service level, not the Web App because that's where you'd do the scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://github.com/greenfinch/sample-net-AzureApplicationInsightsStatusMonitor/blob/master/StatusMonitorSample/WorkerRole/Role_Start/InstallStatusMonitor.ps1#L176). This is a custom solution, not from AI team, but it does the right thing - the account of the application pool on the box should have access to Performance Monitor to be able to read Performance Counter values and report them to AI.